# Problem in the keyboard screen by Input Field TMP in the unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why when I select InputField TMP in the unity c#  the keyboard screen appears correctly, but when I select another InputField TMP  it disappears and I have to click on it again for it to appear. I want to keep keyboard screen when moving from one InputField TMP  to another without disappearing

Why when I select InputField TMP in the unity c#  the keyboard screen appears correctly, but when I select another InputField TMP  it disappears and I have to click on it again for it to appear. I want to keep keyboard screen when moving from one InputField TMP  to another without disappearing

Comment: The reason for that is that after the first click into the input field it enters edit mode. At the same time it also spawns an invisible UI blocker panel which blocks the entire screen, making the input field a modal input. So any click outside of the Input field only exits the edit mode. Therefore you need also the other click for entering the next input field => I don't think you can change that behavior (currently not on a PC) but maybe you can inherit the TMP Input field and enhance it with custom behavior

Comment: See [TMP_InputField source code](https://github.com/k1lly0u/RustEdit-Unity/blob/46431f6214f737b8b7ca5118ae6c3ca3c0251b5b/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro%402.0.1/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_InputField.cs#L2029) I think the issue is here and it `Use`s the event so it is not further handled by other UI elements ... Not a UI blocker though how I thought first .. that's only used by `Dropdown` ^^